# Why does the brace appear small and not group all the lines of the system?

Tags: formatting

The commands used are:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[portuguese,brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
\usepackage{mathptmx}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper,  total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
m&\equiv&1&(mod~2)\\
n&\equiv&0&(mod~3)\\
m&\equiv&0&(mod~5)\\
n&\equiv&1&(mod~5)\\
m&\equiv&1&(mod~7)
\end{array}
\right 
$$
Or:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
m&\equiv&1&(mod~2)\\
m&\equiv&0&(mod~5)\\
m&\equiv&1&(mod~7)
\end{array}
\right
\qquad
e
\qquad
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
n&\equiv&0&(mod~3)\\
n&\equiv&1&(mod~5)\\
\end{array}
\right 
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why loading `fourier`, `erewhon` *and* `mathptmx`? You're shooting on your own foot. Besides, you should *never* disregard error messages you get. And you shouldn't use `$$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in loading both `portuguese` and `brazil`. Also, it is *wrong* to load `fourier` along with `mathptmx`, which is the precise cause for the issue.

If you want only a left delimiter, you need `\right.`, not simply `\right`: never disregard error messages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\usepackage{mathptmx}       

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={170mm,257mm},
  left=20mm,
  top=20mm,
%  bottom=2cm, % overspecification!
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
  m &\equiv 1 \pmod{2} \\
  n &\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
  m &\equiv 0 \pmod{5} \\
  n &\equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\
  m &\equiv 1 \pmod{7}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `bottom=2cm` is redundant: you cannot specify `top`, `textheight` (via `total`) *and* `bottom`.

You may want, instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}`,

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Note also the correct way to input “mod”.

[image]